# question about how to make cloud confirmation number generator?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here is the situation. we are doing B2B business. once our international distributors make an order from us, we have to make an order sheet to several factories. And, we have many differernt international distributors and differernt international factory, therefore we do have different time zone officer will handle the order sheet. But the order sheet we are giving factories must be in an certain format EX: A1, A2, A3, A4....etc

So my question is how to build an cloud confirmation number generator?
when each staff is doing the order sheet. they must go online and fill up certain form (distributor name, factory name, order date.....etc)
and after submit, the cloud generator will give them each confirmation number ( but the format of confirmation must can be set as factory need, and should be continuious number, this time is A2, then next time should be A3.....etc)

I don't have idea how to approach this. 
Is that to write php and build the form, and it will save to mysql, and also call mysql to catch the confirmation number? and what's the trick to do the confirmation number as the list we have? I only know how to do the random one.

and tricks to do it?
and is there any good base can be modified as my need will be very appreciated...

best regard,

KJ

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would actually be to do this in a Transactional Stored Procedure at the Database.

This would then allow you in the SP to get the last order number and create and return a new one.

This would probably involve inserting a 'blank' order with the newly created ID, and then your PHP would update rather than insert when it comes to using it.

Doing it in a SP with a Transaction will protect the DB while fetching so nothing can affect the table while it works out and creates the new order, this will ensure no duplicates are formed.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways to do this, you could keep it in a format that is human readable. An example for your case would be (Assuming mapping of distributor to factories is many to many)

```
[distributor-id]-[factory-id]-[order-id]-[auto-increment-number]
```

I am not sure if order-id is auto-increment-number itself for you, just customize it for your needs.

Hope this helps!